# Can I take a running process and redirect its stderr / stdout?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I'm running a find.  It's generating a lot of "Permission denied" errors, that I really don't care about.

Other than by stopping that find, and starting a new one that sends all errors to /dev/null?

What I'd like to do:

```
ctrl-z
fg 2> /dev/null
```

But that doesn't appear to work

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin